# Nested List comprehension on list of nested object list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I defined two classes. MyClassA.attrA2 is a list of two MyClassB objects.

```
class MyClassB():
    def __init__(self,attr):
        self.attrB=attr
        
class MyClassA():
    def __init__(self,attr1,attr2,attr3):
        self.attrA1 = attr1
        self.attrA2 = [MyClassB(attr2),MyClassB(attr3)]

mylist = [MyClassA(1,10,100),MyClassA(2,20,200),MyClassA(3,30,300)]
```

To create the following list of list, I use the following code

```
attrBlist=[]
for i in mylist:
    for j in i.attrA2:
        attrBlist.append([i.attrA1,j.attrB])
print(attrBlist)
```

It works but as I am a python beginner, I wonder if there is a solution with nested list comprehension. I tried many things I do not succeed.

Comment: `[[i.attrA1, j.attrB] for i in mylist for j in i.attrA2]`

Comment: While I am sure @python_user comment is good/correct, I'd advise you to stick to for loops for the moment: for loops are easy to write (as you demonstrated), you can debug a for loop, you can add print statements, etc. - all things that aren't possible in a list comprehension and even less so in a nested comprehension, which are much harder for novices to write (as you demonstrated). Your time learning Python would be better spent getting broad experience rather than trying/failing/trying again/failing again to write one-liners.